# Json Schema required validation

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have my json schema where all values are required. For example:

```
....
{
"properties" : {
   "minimumDelay" : {
            "type" : "number"
        },
   "length" : {
            "type" : "number"
        },
}, 
"required": {
   "minimumDelay",
   "length"
}
```

Here the json data will be valid if I enter both minimumDelay and length values.

But my requirement is json data must be valid when I enter either 1 of the values(like XOR case). How my schema must be modified to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

In JSON Schema, the XOR operator is `oneOf`.

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "minimumDelay" : {
      "type" : "number"
    },
    "length" : {
      "type" : "number"
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    { "required": ["minimumDelay"] },
    { "required": ["length"] }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this just mean that _at least_ one is required. You need to specifically state that if one is provided, the other must not be provided at all (whereas what you have here is "one of them must be provided, the other can be but doesn't _have_ to be)..

Comment: This is correct. `anyOf` means that at least one is required. `oneOf` means exactly one is required. If more than one is valid, the `oneOf` fails. I see that most people use `oneOf` when they should be using `anyOf`. I think the names confuse people. This one of the rare cases where `oneOf` is actually the right choice.

Comment: Ahh yes, very clever, I didn't fully consider the mutual exclusivity of the oneOf!